# Javascript Worker Performance without onMessage

Tags: javascript, performance, web-worker

I have observed an odd behavior of web workers.
Assume worker.js to containt the code below

```
onmessage = 
function(event) 
{
 var x = event.data;
 var c = 0;
 
 for(var i = 0; i < x; i++) c = c + Math.random();
 
 postMessage(c);
}
```

I create and worker, post "100000000" to it, to run it for 100 millions loops.
It takes around 900 milliseconds.

Now, consider the same code, without an onmessage event.
It will run right away after being created, without having to trigger it through postMessage.

```
 var x = 100000000;
 var c = 0;
 
 for(var i = 0; i < x; i++) c = c + Math.random();
 
 postMessage(c);
```

Same 100 millions loops,
but this this time it takes on average 2200 milliseconds.
More than double.

Is there any explanation for this performance gap?
A compilation issue perhaps?

**Update**, as requested, this is how performance is measured:

```
var worker = new Worker('worker.js');
var time   = performance.now();
worker.onmessage =
function(event)
{ 
 time = performance.now() - time;
}
```

Comment: How do you measure how long it takes?

Comment: performance.now(). But just push those 100 millions to 1 billion and it becomes evident even without in-code measurements.

Comment: Where, please show it in your snippets too.

Comment: Is `test_worker` supposed to be simply `worker`? Or is there another worker instance involved?

Comment: Ah so you do measure the time it takes to receive the event on the main thread, not really the time it takes to execute the loop on the worker thread. A lot might come in between then.

Comment: @Pointy  yes it was a mistake.

Comment: @Kaiido nothing happens between those, it's just a test, there is no other code running. And as said, all it takes is to run them in sequence with 1 billion loops and you can see the time gap even on a stopwatch.  If there was a difference in the time it takes to receive the result, it would still be a quirky behavior: why there should be such a gap, in the postMessage-less version?

Comment: No, I mean between the call `new Worker()` and the event `onmessage` on the main thread. There are a lot of variables in play: a network request, the initialization of a full JS context + event loop, the detangling of the message channel, etc. What happens is surprising, but it's a lot of variables for where it could come from. That's all I was saying.

Comment: @Kaiido you're right. I moved the performance test inside the workers, and they take the same time. It's the data being posted, that somehow takes much longer. Now, this is hard to explain in itself. It's even weirder if you think that it seems to scale: the longer the worker takes to execute, the longer postMessage "stalls".  And it's consistent:  8 seconds for the version with onMessage, 21 seconds for the version without it.

Comment: Actually I tried on my end and I could see the issue in the worker thread itself. (see my answer below). This last comment is quite confusing...

Comment: @Kaiido you're right again, yes I was wrong - postMessage has nothing to do with it, the worker itself is executed much slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

V8 developer here.

What's happening here is that accessing (in particular: writing to) global variables is slower than accessing function-local variables, mostly because optimized code can keep the latter in registers, but not the former.

This is not a bug, not related to workers, and everything is getting optimized.

Luckily, real-world code almost never has hot code in the top level, so this is mostly just another microbenchmarking artifact.

Reduced example:

```js
(function fast() {
  var x = 100000000;
  const t1 = performance.now();
  for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {};  // i is local
  const t2 = performance.now();
  console.log("fast", t2 - t1);
})();
(function slow() {
  var x = 100000000;
  const t1 = performance.now();
  for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {};  // oops, forgot `var`, i is global
  const t2 = performance.now();
  console.log("slow", t2 - t1);
})();
```

Putting code into the toplevel scope is another variant of `function slow`, because all variables are global variables there.

Comment: Gosh, I did test in a scope block too, but I must have left `c` as a `var` when I did... I knew it was worth asking you to have a look ;-) Thanks, that makes perfect sense.